# How to manage onclick on dyanamically generated checkbox in android

Tags: android

I have created multiple checkboxes via applying looping.

```
for(int l=0;l<len;l++)
{
chkBox = dynamicUiComponents.myCheckBox(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), 100+i, "Unchecked", opts[l]);
myLayout.addView(chkBox);
}
```

All the check boxes are showing. But when I am applying setOnCheckedChangeListener(l) on that check box, then only last added check box text is printer. Its because every time in loop, I provide a new object reference to the chkBox variable. So here how to identify that which chechbox is clicked.

Comment: I found this very hard to understand. You might get better results if you rephrase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you did not create an array of `CheckBoxes`, you only created one. So, using `setOnCheckChangedListener(I)` will not refer to the `checkBox`. Either you set the listener inside the loop, or give each a unique ID to refer to it later and set the listener:

```
for(int l=0;l<5;l++) { chkBox = new CheckBox(context); 
chkBox.setOnCheckChangedListener(
//your implementation
);
myLayout.addView(chkBox); }
```

Comment: If the issue is not just setting the listener, then you can assign Id using View.setId or use View.setTag as in Jamshid or rahul answers.

Comment: This is a code which returns a checkbox. But I have to use a single variable to assign each checkbox created via this.for(int l=0;l<len;l++)
{
chkBox = dynamicUiComponents.myCheckBox(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), 100+i, "Unchecked", opts[l]);
myLayout.addView(chkBox);
} How to identify which checkbox is clicked, chkBox always have the reference of the last checkbox created. Am I right...?

Comment: If you set the listener before returning the View (use l if you need to differentiate between listeners), then each will have it set. Otherwise, give each an id and set the listener per Id

Comment: There is an issue... I want to select multiple checkbox and want to send a String value of all selected checkbox's text seprated by ",". How can I achieve that. Is there any way to check out which checkbox is checked on clicking on submit button apart.

Comment: This is a different question, however, you can do it many different ways. The easiest I can think of is to append a global string variable each time the Checkbox is checked. Another way is to use the ViewGroup.getChildAt (ViewGroup is the container of the checkboxes) to loop through the CheckBoxes and get the value of checked ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can add id to tag:

```
for(int id=0;id<5;id++) { 
 chkBox = new CheckBox(context);
 chkBox.setTag(id); 
 myLayout.addView(chkBox); 
}
```

and you may use:

```
Integer i = (Integer) chkBox.getTag();
```

Comment: I am doing : for(int l=0;l<len;l++)
{ chkBox = dynamicUiComponents.myCheckBox(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), 100+i, "Unchecked", opts[l]);myLayout.addView(chkBox);}   chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
if(chkBox.isChecked())
{
Log.i("SELECTED ITEM :", ""+buttonView.getText());
}
else
{
}
}
});

Comment: Please tell me how to apply setOnCheckedChangedListener() via tag. I think it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
for(int l=0;l<5;l++) 
{ 
    chkBox = new CheckBox(context); 
    myLayout.addView(chkBox); 
    chkBox.setTag(""+l);
    chkBox.setOnCheckChangeListener(new ...(){   
        int x = Integer.ValueOf(chkBox.getTag());
        //do whatever you want to do here
    });
}
```

Comment: This code is using in loop to create checkboxes :                   chkBox = dynamicUiComponents.myCheckBox(context, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT), 100+i, "Unchecked", opts[l]); myLayout.addView(chkBox);

Comment: I want to get the text correspond to the checkbox, as I click on anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different tag for each Checkbox and set the listener on THIS, you activity should implement the listener and then do whatever you want when the event is trigger.